# `rake test` command tests wrong model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write some tests. The first one is very simple, and tests that a resource wont save without a title. Running `rake test test/models/item_test.rb` gives this error:

```
Run options: --seed 8410

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.027193s, 36.7740 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1) Error:
ItemTest#test_should_not_save_item_without_title:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "admin_users" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "admin_users"
                ^
: DELETE FROM "admin_users"


1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

My test code is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 test "should not save item without title" do
  item = Item.new
  assert_not item.save
 end
end
```

Why is `admin_users` getting pulled into that? This happens when testing *any* resource.

Comment: Does your `spec_helper.rb` file have the following line in it: `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`? I'm guessing the schema on the test database is not up to date.

Comment: @james00794 I'm following this, which says nothing about rspec or `spec_helper.rb`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html.  Is rspec just an unmentioned assumption?

Comment: No you are right, that guide is for the built-in test framework that comes with Rails. Did you prepare the test database as that guide explains (`rake db:test:prepare`)?

Comment: I did. It seems to have done nothing.

Comment: Have you built a test database? i.e. `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails generator must have created a file in the `test/fixtures` directory that doesn’t correspond to any actual tables in your database or you might have forgotten to remove one when deleting a model :) Anyway, to resolve the issue make sure to remove the `test/fixtures/admin_users.yml`. This might require removing other autogenerated fixtures as well.